# Why package does not appear in sublime text 2 Package Control?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

I would like to install new package ([rsync-ssh](https://github.com/davidolrik/sublime-rsync-ssh)) in my Sublime Text 2 editor. I already have installed [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/).

I followed Installation steps:

> ... installing it via the excellent Package Control plugin. Press ⌘⇧P and type Package Control: Install Package and select it, then type the package name rsync-ssh and select it.

But this package is not available on list, see img:
[image]

Any ideas? I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 15.04), I installed Sublime Text few days ago, so is quite new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked out the package you want to install on the package control website and I think it is exclusively available only for Sublime Text 3. 
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Rsync%20SSH
Try uninstalling ST2 and install ST3 instead and that should help to fix the issue you are currently having, because I have ST3 and the package is available to me.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me to Sublime Text 3 version. I wasn't sure if I will use it, but it looks perfect

Comment: You're welcome :) It's supposedly still in beta but as the official site says, has a LOT of improvements and more features as compared to ST2 . Best of luck :)